# java - Использование массивов

Tags: java

Нужно перемножить все числа с индексами в диапазоне от 20 до 30

Умножает все, не могу установить условие

```
 int[] array = new int[18];
 for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 array[i] = (int) Math.round((Math.random() * 57) + 15);
 System.out.println(array[i]);
 }

 double mul = 1;

  for (int j = 0; j < 18; ++j)
     if (array[j] >=18) {
         for(int z=0;z<array[31];z++)

        mul *= array[j];
     }
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял условие, то в Вашем случае выполнить его не возможно, т.к. в Вашем массиве нет элементов с индексам от 20 до 30, т.к. Вы создаете массив длинной 18. Соответственно в Вашем массиве могут быть только элементы с индексами от 0 до 17.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 0; j < array.length; ++j)
            if (array[j] >= 20 && array[j] <= 30)
                    mul *= array[j];
```